# How does systemd send a message to a service to elicit a sd_notify(3) response?

Tags: c, daemon, systemd, status, shutdown

I'm having trouble understanding Systemd's model for notifications and a couple of workflows. Systemd notifications occur using [`sd_notify (3)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) interface. The `sd_notify (3)` interfaces provide a way for a daemon to tell systemd its state:

```
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>

int sd_notify(int unset_environment,
    const char *state);

int sd_notifyf(int unset_environment,
    const char *format,
    ...);

...
```

If I am parsing the man page correctly, a daemon should call `sd_notify(0, "READY=1\n");` once it is started and ready to process data. And when it stops it should call `sd_notify(0, "STOPPING=1\n");`.

Here is one of the workflows I am having trouble with. I don't see how Systemd delivers a message to the daemon saying *"update your status"* so it can be reported to the user via `systemctl status`.

```
systemctl status mydaemon.service
```

Another workflow I am having trouble with is shutdown. I don't see how Systemd delivers a shutdown message to the daemon.

In both cases I feel like my executable should export a function and Systemd should call into it for the queries and messages.

How does Systemd tell the daemon to report its status or shutdown?

Answer (score 2):

In general, systemd *doesn't* send a message to your daemon. Your daemon should generate the status notifications *every* time the internal status changes. Otherwise, if your process hung (temporarily or permanently), the user's request for status wouldn't do anything. Note that the daemon's output is also shown, so it might not be necessary to always call `sd_notify`.

Stopping should usually be handled by a signal, or possibly using `ExecStop=` to run a `fooctl` process that sends a message over a socket and waits for a reply.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with *"generate the status notifications every time the internal status changes"* is, it only says what the state was some time in the past. It cannot report hung processes, which seems like a reason someone would `systemctl status mydaemon.service`. (It is the same problem code signing suffers - the attestation only applies to some code at some time in the past. It does not say anything about the currently executing code).

Comment: To clarify, under the way you described, you wouldn't get any status output *at all*. With the way it actually works, you simply get the last update, which is useful to answer "what was it *doing* at the time of the hang". If you want to catch the hang itself, set `WatchdogSec=`.